# What is the recommended way to revert a specific change in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, revert

I have a file in which several separate blocks have changed in one changeset. (This is not the most recent changeset.)

Now I need to revert just one of these blocks to the status of the revision right before those changes. What is the recommended procedure for this? Does Mercurial/TortoiseHg offer any help, or should I just manually replace this block with the old contents?

Answer (score 1):

If you would want a complete changeset being undone, it could be done without manual work by using `hg backout`. From its help:

> hg backout [OPTION]... [-r] REV
>
> reverse effect of earlier changeset
>
> Prepare a new changeset with the effect of REV undone in the current
>      working directory. If no conflicts were encountered, it will be committed
>      immediately.
>
> If REV is the parent of the working directory, then this new changeset is
>      committed automatically (unless --no-commit is specified).
>
> Note:
>         'hg backout' cannot be used to fix either an unwanted or incorrect
>          merge.

However as you only want a single hunk reverted, you can use `hg backout` and then you need to use the `--interactive` flag for the commit so that you can pick the right hunk(s) to be committed:

```
hg commit --message "Revert some stuff" --interactive
```

Last, revert the working dir to a now unmodified state - you don't want to change back the remaining hunks